# Create a table from view?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

is it possible in MySQL? In Oracle I could do:

```
SELECT *
INTO table
FROM view
```

In MySQL, this does not work:

```
INSERT INTO table FROM view;
```

Remember that the table does not exist. I want it to be created based on output from the view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a SELECT right after table name:

```
CREATE TABLE new_tbl SELECT * FROM orig_tbl;
```

More information available here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table-select.html

Answer (score 5):

In MySQL you can create a new table [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html) another table but that doesn't work with views.

You can also create a [new table that contains everything from a select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-select.html), that works from views, selects, joins and everything else. Note that the new table will hold all data from  the select so you have to be tricky. Like this.

```
create table table_from_view select * from view_name where 1 = 0;
```

You have to add indexes afterwards if you need them.